# Assert that node exists containing text from two child nodes in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `lazyColumn()` in compose with each item in the list containing two text view elements. One item has text elements `Foo` and `Bar`.

The compose semantics tree has merged these two texts into the parent node so `composeRule.onRoot().printToLog()` outputs `Text = '[Foo, Bar]'`.

How can I assert that a node exists with both text elements `Foo` and `Bar`?

I have tried the below but get `could not find any node that satisfies: ((Text + EditableText contains 'Foo' (ignoreCase: false)) && (Text + EditableText contains 'Bar' (ignoreCase: false))`

```
composeRule.onNode(hasText("Foo") and hasText("Bar"), useUnmergedTree = true).assertExists()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're talking about a node in the merged tree but then searching for a node using the unmerged tree. Remove `unmergedTree = true`

```kotlin
composeRule.onNode(hasText("Foo") and hasText("Bar")).assertExists()
```

To see the difference between merged and unmerged you can use `composeRule.onRoot(useUnmergedTree = true/false).printToLog()`

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you just need to change the `and` to `or`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).